# How to clean up chrome.storage.local?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to remove all the data stored in chrome.storage.local according to they keys that I'v e used in storing them but running this on the console didn't work:

```
var storage= chrome.storage.local;
storage.remove('filters');
```

Comment: When you say doesn't work, what do you mean?

Comment: It says undefined when I try this: var storage= chrome.storage.local;

Comment: Like it just says `undefined` after you enter that line, or storage is undefined?

Comment: Where did you execute the code? In the console of a normal webpage where your extension injected a content script?